# How to get SoftLayer virtual guest by tags, what's the mask for tags?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I can get virtual guests by masks like "id", "hostname", "primaryIpAddress" etc.
However, I need to get virtual guests with specific tags.
What's the mask to use to retrieve tagged virtual guests?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Objectfilter:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

see this example using RESTFul request

```
URL : https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"tagReferences":{"tag":{"name":{"operation":"in","options":[{"name":"data","value":["$tag1","$tag2"]}]}}}}}

Method: GET

Note: replace $tag1 and $tag2 with the tags you wish
```

Regards

Comment: Yes, but the sldn article gives an example using 'datacenter' and 'name' as mask for filtering. I have no problem using 'datacenter[name]' as mask in my code to retrieve virtual guests. However, if I change my mask to tagReferences[tag[name]] and keep all the code code as before,  I get Exception: HTTP-Error: 500 Internal Server Error. The RESTful GET seems to indicate tagReferences[tag[name]] is the filter to use.

Comment: I do not understand :S, Did the Restful I give you work?

Comment: by the way the object mask is  objectMask=mask[tagReferences[tag[name]]] , but it will return all the VMs, if you are looking the VMs with specific tags you need to use the objectFilter

Comment: The HTTP-Error: 500 Internal Server Error is likely because the result of your request have a big amount of data and you need to use limits see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491538/internal-server-error-when-get-the-tags-of-the-virtual-guest for add limits in a Restful request see http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest#Using_Result_Limits

Answer (score 0):

I got some help. Here is the Ruby code to do it:

```
client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: USERNAME, api_key: API_KEY)
account_service = client['SoftLayer_Account']
object_filter = SoftLayer::ObjectFilter.new
object_filter.set_criteria_for_key_path(
'virtualGuests.tagReferences.tag.name', 'operation' => 'in',
'options' => [{
'name' => 'data',
'value' => tagsToFind
}])
mask = 'mask[tagReferences[tag[name]]]'
result = account_service.object_mask(mask).
object_filter(object_filter).getVirtualGuests
```